# How do I Connect to A Unix Server From SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

In my SharePoint site users will raise a request and a workflow will mail to the team. Then we have to run a Unix script. I want to automate this manual process. How can I connect to a Unix server from SharePoint? Once a request is submitted, a workflow has to be triggered to run the script.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you set up some type of service on your unix server that SharePoint can connect to.

Very basic example with netcat :

```
nc -l -p 9001 -e myscript.sh
```

And pinging your server:

```
using System.Net;
const string url = "http://dev.eirikb.no:9001";
WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse();
```